# SyntaxError: invalid syntax if __name__ = "__main__":

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

```
#! usr/bin python3

import  urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
        response = urllib.request.urlopen()
        return response.read()

def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

def main():
    print(get_html('http://av.by/public/index.php?event=3&category_id=1864&show_new=0')

if __name__ =  "__main__":
    main()
```

Ошибка

```
File "avby.py", line 16
  if __name__ =  "__main__":
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Сравнение во многих языках - "==".

Comment: исправил на ==, но ситуация не изменилась.

Comment: Значит, не исправили. Копипаст вашей проблемной строки и исправление оператора на правильный не вызывает сообщений об ошибках.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов У него в коде у `print`'а скобка не закрыта.

Comment: @kff и в самом деле, ошибка не одна...

Comment: Всем большое спасибо.
Невнимательный я :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В языке программирования `Python` символ `=` означает *присваивание*, в то время как условный оператор ожидает результат *сравнения*. Для того, чтобы ликвидировать ошибку, необходимо использовать оператор сравнения, который в `Python` записывается как `==`.

P.S. И скобку у `print`'а закройте!

Comment: if __name__== "__main__":
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Ситуация не изменилась

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik Скобку у print'а закройте!